# prevent tablet downloads of app

Tags: android, bitmap, tablet

I have recently been looking at the breakdown of one of my apps on ANdroid Market, and was surprised to see that a number of downloaders were using Galaxy Tabs and a few other tablets to use my app. 
Now, I'm a little worried, because when designing the app I didn't take into account larger screen sizes, so the bitmaps I used on the Canvas are all suitable for phone sizes but are way too small for tablets (I'm thinking of the background bitmaps which will cover about 1/4 of the Galaxy Tab's screen. The thought of people using my app like this is making me feel a little unnerved. 
So my question is, is there a way to prevent Tablet PCs from downloading an app? I'm guessing not, but I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

But I suspect that it will prevent your app to run on Galaxy Tab but you can gave it a try

Comment: ingsaurabh your code works perfectly for the 10 inch Tab. But I'm unable to block the Nexus 7 tab. Please give suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<compatible-screens>` element to prevent, for example, devices with x-large screens from seeing your app in Google Play.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887074/targeting-different-specs-in-android-app-submission/5887168#5887168) has been going around a lot recently and it seems that you cannot stop people from downloading and installing your app based on their device-type.

A couple things you can try are:

1. Create an extra set of images for the higher def devices
2. Check the resolution on initial app run and either tell them that their device is not supported (and exit) or warn them that it may not look so good.