# How to prevent app installing on tablet in Android?

Tags: android, mobile, installation

I am told to build an app in Android 2.2 which will not support tablets.

I went through lots of googling but found no solution. I also found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892260/prevent-tablet-downloads-of-app) but this give how to do the same from 2.3 onwards.

My problem is that I can't switch to 2.3 as my client want to support the app from 2.2.

Here is the code I am using in my manifest

```
<supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

The code above doesn't prevent the app to download from tablet, and so it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The code in that link will work fine. Set your sdkTarget to 2.3 and your minSDK as 2.2.

Comment: Thank you for a very quick reply. but will my app run on 2.2? I also found from http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html - Caution: By default, all screen size attributes in the <supports-screens> element are "true" if you do not declare them otherwise. However, because the android:xlargeScreens attribute was added in Android 2.3 (API level 9), Google Play will assume that it is "false" if your application does not set either android:minSdkVersion or android:targetSdkVersion to "9" or higher. but have no idea if this will work

Answer (score 1):

A little bit unexpected answer, I think, but have your tried to ignore screen sizes completely and just request `PHONE` features in the manifest? It's quite rare for a tablet to have those, so you effectively filter 'em out. For example, your may write in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: can you please mention few such features

Comment: great idea!! but my viewsonic tablet has phone feature

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="false"
                  android:anyDensity="false" />
```